# Meaning of .-main expression

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

What does this expression mean:

```
.-main
```

in context of:

```
.size   main, .-main
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the dot `.` means "current location".

Then `.-main` would be the distance to the start of main. If placed at the end of main, it would also be the *size* of main.

Comment: so "-" means minus and this expression means "size of main" = "." (current address) minus "address of main"?

Comment: Yes, it is "here" minus address of "main". That would also be the size of main, if it is placed immediately after the end of main.