# What does code pattern like .size X,.-X do?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, eabi

My question is about some popular but not well documented code I have found in ARM CORTEX M startup files like [this STM32](https://github.com/tmdarwen/STM32/blob/master/STM32F411/ArmCortexM4Analysis/startup.s).

The 'pattern' is:

```
.size X,.-X
```

,where X is a symbol or label.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058361/meaning-of-main-expression) and understand how *.size* directive and *dot special symbol* work, but still complete line seems to do nothing to me. The result of the operation *.-X* isn't stored anywhere.

Could anybody explain what the line does?

Comment: The result is stored in the metadata automatically by the `.size` directive.

Comment: The size calculation works exactly like `$ - X` in NASM: [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744).  But the `.size` directive emits ELF metadata with the function size, which is useful for shared libraries.

Comment: Thank you for answers! What will happen if I do not put this code after the function? Will it have negative impact on optimization only or my code won't work as expected?

Comment: The effect of leaving it out is stuff like [ARM Assembly Functions Appear With Size 0 in Symtab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52820466).  I'm not sure if there are implications for correctness of static or dynamic linking.  But it's just metadata, so if it works at all, there aren't any performance implications.

Comment: If you miss it out it might affect how well the debugging of the assembler works for the reasons in the comment above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is placed at the end of function X, and the size of the function is the difference between the end of the function and the beginning. `.` is the current location so it's saying .size x is the difference between here and the label `x`.