# ARM Assembly Functions Appear With Size 0 in Symtab

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I have a simple handwritten asm file, which I compile to ARM using the command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc test.s -c -o sof.out --specs=nosys.specs -mthumb -O0
```

When viewing the object file with objdump, the code appears correct.
**However, when I read the symbol table (using readelf), the functions appear in size 0.**

This is messing with some of my analysis programs.

Why do the functions appear with size 0?
Is there anything I can do in the asm file or the compiler flags, to fix this?

Comment: Use a `.size` directive.  [What does code pattern like .size X,.-X do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52818114)